ACF autocomplete fields not working in a second form on a page, with acf_form
I've an issue about autocomplete fields with ACF.
I've created two forms with acf_form function in a reserved area. In these forms a user can create new post.
Then, I wanted create an autocomplete field where, If a user set a word in a text field and send the form, while crating another post, the user see the word set before:
test acf field autocomplete
To set this I installed a custom plugin: https://github.com/christianmagill/acf-autocomplete
In the first form it working fine, but in a second form in the same page, it isn't working and I don't understand why.
This is the js code of plugin:
(function($){
    
    
    function initialize_field( $el ) {
    
        $(':text:visible',$el).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response  ){
                
                if(!request.term.trim().length)
                    response( [] );
                
                if (!(key = $el.data('field_name'))) {
                    key = $el.data('key');
                }
                
                $.getJSON( ajaxurl, { 
                        'action' : 'autocomplete_ajax',
                        'field_key' : key,
                        'request' : request.term.trim()
                    }, function( data ){
                    
                    response( data );
                    
                });
            }
        });
    }
    
    if( typeof acf.add_action !== 'undefined' ) {
    
        /*
        *  ready append (ACF5)
        */
        
        acf.add_action('ready append', function( $el ){
            
            // search $el for fields of type 'autocomplete'
            acf.get_fields({ type : 'autocomplete'}, $el).each(function(){
                
                initialize_field( $(this) );
                
            });
            
        });
        
        
    } else {
        
        
        /*
        *  acf/setup_fields (ACF4)
        */
        
        $(document).on('acf/setup_fields', function(e, postbox){
            
            $(postbox).find('.field[data-field_type="autocomplete"]').each(function(){
                
                initialize_field( $(this) );
                
            });
        
        });
    
    
    }


})(jQuery);

Can anyone help me please?
I try to modify Javascript file and php form.

NOTE:
I've notated that the issue presents because I've a tab of Bootstrap in my code. On one tab I see a form, If I click to second tab I see the other form. And If I delete code of tabs content it working fine.
But tabs must to be setted
